# How to design the layout in listview (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am beginner in flutter. I am trying to design this screen in flutter but I am not able to do it. Please help me.

This is the design:

[image]

Comment: Show what you have done so far.

Comment: Actually I didn't do that much yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ListTile` inside a list view builder. The leading property would be a `Container` with `ClipPath`. You can then use Text widgets for title and subtitle.

### Code

You can achieve this with the ClipPath widget and CustomClipper:

```dart
ListView.builder(

   builder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
                leading: ClipPath(clipper: Cut(), child: MyWidget()),
          )

}

);

class Cut extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
```

Comment: Okay but how can I make that divider line which is not straight ?

Comment: check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `CustomPainter` .

Check this online [tool](https://shapemaker.web.app/#/) which generates the code of the shapes you draw. It's a good starting point for custom shapes and how the code works.